# replace associative array of one file to another file index array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist, associative-array

I have two files ConfigAuthGroups.php and AuthGroups.php in ConfigAuthGroups.php file have index array and AuthGroups.php have associative array, i want to replace associative array with index array.

index array in ConfigAuthGroups.php

```
 public array $groups = ['GroupsArr'];
```

associative array in AuthGroups.php

```
  public array $groups = [
        'superadmin' => [
            'title'       => 'Super Admin',
            'description' => 'Complete control of the site.',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'title'       => 'Admin',
            'description' => 'Day to day administrators of the site.',
        ],
        'developer' => [
            'title'       => 'Developer',
            'description' => 'Site programmers.',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'title'       => 'User',
            'description' => 'General users of the site. Often customers.',
        ],
        'salmanbhai' => [
            'title'       => 'Beta User',
            'description' => 'Has access to beta-level features.',
        ],
    ];
```

I have tried with `str_replace` but not worked for me. it giving me Array to string conversion Error.

```
$config_path  = APPPATH . 'Config/ConfigAuthGroups.php';
$replace_path = APPPATH . "Config/AuthGroups.php";

// read array from AuthGroups
$authGroups = setting('AuthGroups.groups');

// Open the file
$replace = file_get_contents($config_path);

$newArr = $authGroups;

$new  = str_replace("['GroupsArr']", $authGroups, $replace);


// Write the new AuthGroups.php file
$handle = fopen($replace_path, 'w+');

fwrite($handle, $new);
```

Comment: Maybe this is some code-generation console utility, so why not?)

Comment: Salman, could you please provide more context? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IliaYatsenko Why not? Because [PHP files contain code, not data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642357/whats-the-difference-between-data-and-code). A _"code-generation console utility"_ is quite an exotic thing, and if this question was about that it should have been clearly stated. Yes, more context would be welcome. Currently we have no idea what Salman is trying to achive and why.

Comment: Use array_values() to strip out key names. It isn't clear to me why you would want to do this. Is it just to save space?

Comment: what information do you need more? I am working on a project all configuration is saved in the config file and I need to update it from the frontend, not go to files and do it manually

Comment: if I place an associative array in string format it works like "[
        'superadmin' => [
            'title'       => 'Super Admin',
            'description' => 'Complete control of the site.',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'title'       => 'Admin',
            'description' => 'Day to day administrators of the site.',
        ]
    ]"

Comment: as I assume and work I need to convert an associative array to a string then it will work for me but not able to do it if can give suggestion will be thankful to you.

Comment: I read your comments, but I don't quite understand them. As I said before, you should not write to PHP files, they are meant to hold code, not writable data. Use another file type, if you need to save configuration data, and don't save it as PHP code.